# Convert Oracle sql with "CONNECT BY LEVEL" to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can anyone help to converting following sql to T-SQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM (    SELECT LEVEL n, TO_DATE ('31/12/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL (LEVEL, 'day') CurrDate
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick, I think

```
select dateadd(d, number, '2010-12-31') 
from master..spt_values 
where type='p' 
and number between 1 and 2000
```

Comment: For our purposes, it's a table of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

nevermind... found it...

```
with n as
(
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2010-12-31', '2015-12-31') + 1) 
n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
FROM sys.all_objects
)
 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, '2010-12-31')
 FROM n;
```